# Tikz: Connect two sequences

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to plot two math sequences (a,b,c,d,e,...) and (1,2,3,4,5,6,...) among each other, and to draw an arrow from a to 1, from b to 2 and so on. How can I do this?

Here is my first try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (a) {(7,};
    \node[right=0cmof a] (b) {11,};
    \node[right=0cm of b] (c) {17,};
    \node[right=0cm of c] (d) {26,};
    \node[right=0cm of d] (e) {13,};
    \node[right=0cm of e] (f) {20,};    
    \node[right=0cm of f] (g) {$\dots)$};


   \node (a1) [below=of a] {(1,};
    \node[right=0cmof a1] (b1) {1,};
    \node[right=0cm of b1] (c1) {1,};
    \node[right=0cm of c1] (d1) {0,};
    \node[right=0cm of d1] (e1) {1,};
    \node[right=0cm of e1] (f1) {0,};    
    \node[right=0cm of f1] (g1) {$\dots)$};

    \draw[->] (a) --  (a1);
    \draw[->] (b) --  (b1);
    \draw[->] (c) --  (c1);
    \draw[->] (d) --  (d1);
    \draw[->] (e) --  (e1);
    \draw[->] (f) --  (f1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However this does not really look good:

[image]

I can now adjust the distance between the nodes to make it look accurate, but is there a better approach?

Comment: You can use a foreach statement with two variables iterated simultaneously. See section 83 of the pgf manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your life a little easier and make use of automation by using `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\xi from 0] \x / \y in {7/1,11/1,17/1,26/0,13/1,20/0}{%
    \node (\x_\xi) at (\xi/1.5,1) {\x};
    \node (\y_\xi) at (\xi/1.5,0) {\y};
    \draw[->] (\x_\xi) -- (\y_\xi);
  } 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]